# Index a 2D matrix with a 1D matrix

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, indexing, numpy-ndarray

I have a 2D matrix of values named matrix1 as shown below:

```
col1     col2    col3
1         1        0
2         1        2
```

I have a 1D matrix of values named arr1 as shown below:

```
col1
10
20
30
```

I would like to use values from this 2D matrix to index values from a 1D matrix, creating a new 2D matrix in the process.

```
new_col1      new_col2      new_col3
  20            20             10
  30            20             30
```

The actual arrays is shaped (512,1) and matrix shaped (65672, 720). I have tried using arr1[matrix1] but I end up getting a memory error.

Comment: `arr1[matrix1]` is the easiest way to do this.  What size are your arrays?

Comment: (512,1) and (65672,720)

Comment: What are the dtypes of the dataframes?

Comment: What happens with `matrix1.copy()`?  Another memory error?

Comment: Data types are int32.

Comment: No memory error when I run matrix1.copy()

Answer (score 0):

A Python3 Solution:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([[1, 1, 0], [2, 1, 2]])
y = np.array([10, 20, 30])
y[x]
```

Output:

```
array([[20, 20, 10],
       [30, 20, 30]])
```

Comment: They have tried this.. They state this in their question, but they get a memory error.

Comment: If there's a memory error it's because of the overall memory usage, not specifically a problem with this solution.  The result won't be any bigger than `matrix1`, (65672, 720,1)  (give or take some for the `dtype` of `arr1`).

Answer (score 0):

So I noticed that I was using a 32 bit python interpreter instead of a 64 bit python interpreter ( I am using a virtual environment in pycharm) changing the python interpreter to 64 bit fixed this memory error.